# Nginx failing again & again after sometime

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am having an nginx server and hosting a python fast API app in it and hosting it as a system service. It fails after some random amount of time and below is the error that is being returned in error logs. Please point me in the right direction since I have explored all the available options available online.

[image: Nginx]